How can I use "SchemaName.TableName" partition key in AWS DMS to migrate data to an Amazon Kinesis data stream?
I'm trying to set up DMS to push data to kinesis stream, with partition keys based on the schema and table name. The intent is to get all cdc events for a given table hitting a single shard, to better guarantee on ordering of events for a given table (though I know it's not a 100% guarantee).
I'd like to use the setting that the docs says is supported (and in some other places says is the default!):
"AWS DMS supports the following two forms for partition keys:
SchemaName.TableName: A combination of the schema and table name.
${AttributeName}: The value of one of the fields in the JSON, or the primary key of the table in the source database."
But, I do not see any setting in the AWS console or aws cdk to use the former, and my partition keys are showing as the primary key of the data within the source db (which is aurora postgresSQL, if it matters). I can append the schema and table to the start but that doesn't solve the issue of getting 1 table to 1 shard.
I'd like to have this as a universal setting on the DMS replication task or kinesis settings across all tables, but I did also try all the "object-mapping" approaches in the docs defining a single schema & table, with no success.
My record on the kinesis stream looks like:
{"metadata": {'timestamp': '2024-07-12T22:39:43.800897Z', 'record-type': 'data', 'operation': 'load', 'partition-key-type': 'primary-key', 'schema-name': 'public', 'table-name': 'addresses'}, "PartitionKey":  'public.addresses.f92bbb5e-9782-4917-b9fe-15c747792876'}, ...

And I want it to look like:
{'timestamp': '2024-07-12T22:39:43.800897Z', 'record-type': 'data', 'operation': 'load', 'partition-key-type': 'schema-table', 'schema-name': 'public', 'table-name': 'addresses'},  'PartitionKey': 'public.addresses'}, ...


I tried:

adding a "object-mapping" entry for a single table with mapping_parameters: {"partition-key-type": "schema-table"}
adding a "object-mapping" entry for a single table with mapping_parameters: {"partition-key": {"value": "public_addresses"}}


Hey! @sprague44 Did you manage to resolve it ? I need opposite - distribute records between shards evenly. AWS Support suggest to set UUID as a partition-key, but I don't get what they mean. Currently I am looking how to set 'partition-key-type': 'primary-key' for my CDC task because currently is has "partition-key-type": "schema-table".
